# Changing LC filter passband width

Tags: filter

I am building a circuit that uses an LC bandpass filter (with the inductor and the capacitor in parallel between the signal and ground lines). However I am having a problem in that there is no way that I can tell to change the passband width of the filter.

I have given details of my specific situation below, I am really wanting a general answer: how does one change the passband width of a parallel LC filter? This seems like such a simple question, but Google has failed to give me the answer.

Specific situation: I am trying to build a shortwave radio receiver. As such, I am needing a passband width of somewhere around 5kHz to 10kHz. However with my current component values, which is a 2.844uH inductor and a variable capacitor which at 50pF is supposed to give a tuned frequency of 13.333MHz for the receiver, the passband width is somewhere around 5MHz which is obviously way too high. According to a simulation which I ran, I need to put a 1 megaohm resistor between the antenna and the LC network, but that blocks most of the signal from the antenna.

Comment: I suppose, your filter contains also an ohmic resistor. Did you determine the transfer function of the whole circuit? Have you ever heard about the quality factor of a bandpass? (Ohh - I see, this comment was written in parallel to both answers)

Answer (score 2):

Adding resistance to the LC "tank" circuit will widen the bandwidth, but will ruin the Q of the filter at the same time.  This is a basic tradeoff.   The "Q" (or quality factor) is a measure of how much on-frequency signal gets through, versus how much it can reject the off-frequency signals.

Real schemes to produce wider bandwidth filters use multiple LC's in various combinations, producing a "filter network".  It's still difficult to vary the bandwidth without switching components in or out.

Modern digital signal processing techniques can accomplish these things, as they are substituting "adding more circuits" with "adding more logic elements" and program code.

Comment: Actually I am trying to _narrow_ the bandwidth, but I guess that narrowing it would be the reverse of widening it. Also it is not acceptable in my case to add more networks - I need to use just one, with a narrow bandwidth.

Answer (score -1):

You need to consider that your signal source cannot be zero ohms because the parallel LC connected to it will not offer any significant bandpass shaping. The higher the value of the source resistor the tighter the peak of the bandpass filtering: -

[image]

Depending on the value of the resistor the passband will alter: -

[image]

Pictures taken from [mathworks](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/control/ug/analyzing-the-response-of-an-rlc-circuit.html) and their site shows all the formulas.

One word of warning; inductors have self-resistance and this cannot be disregarded if building a highly resonant band-pass filter. The effect of a small resistor in series with the inductor is the same as lowering R in the pictures above i.e. resonance is less-tight. Also note that feeding the output of the LC into a low impedance amplifier can have the same effect.

Comment: Anyone care to guess why I have been down voted?

Comment: I have tried that, however the problem is that adding the resistor is reducing the source current and thus limiting the power available from my source. At least I _think_ that's what's happening, when I put the resistor in and the output (at the resonant frequency) is very quiet. (The source is a radio antenna, and when I put the resistor in then I am effectively disconnecting the antenna and I get pretty much no signal.)

Comment: @MichealJohnson If the source is an antenna then it already has 30 to 300 ohms source impedance so an extra resistor probably won't be required BUT the quality of your inductor is paramount. You have intentionally not given any values so I can't know what you were attempting.

Comment: Well I didn't really want to give values because then I will probably receive answers such as "use a superhet receiver" or other such "solutions" which might deal with the greater issue but are not specific to what I am trying to do. But what sort of resistor value would I need? A simulation that I ran indicated that I need a resistor around 1 megaohm, but such value of resistor essentially disconnects the antenna by blocking almost all the signal (and probably doesn't do much for the passband width).

Comment: Try altering L and C values to get the same resonant frequency but work better with tens of ohms of resistance.

Comment: At some point, there are things you just can't do, or you need to add an amplifier to make up for the inserted loss.  Or, you manage to get what you want, but now the filter is only -6dB outside the passband instead of -40.  There's a reason for all those fancy circuits people come up with.